# Connecting multiple container replicas to a single container without port conflicts

Tags: docker, docker-compose, port

I currently have two types of Docker containers: a redis server, and a Node.js app. With just one of each, I can get them to interact just fine. The redis server listens for connections on the default port 6379. The Node.js app connects using

```
const redis_client = redis.createClient({
  socket: {
    host: 'redis-server', # name of the redis container in my docker-compose.yml
    port: 6379,
  }
});
```

and in its docker-compose.yml definition has

```
node-app:
  # ...other configs...
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"
```

This works, all is well and good.

I'm now trying to scale this up to allow for several Node.js app container instances to interact with one redis container instance. I originally tried adding

```
deploy:
  replicas: 2
```

to my node-app definition, but on `$ docker compose up -d` this throws `Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:6379 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:6379: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.`

How can I attach multiple containers to one container in a way that's scalable (i.e. not just hardcoding two node-app instances)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to create multiple replicas of the same service running on different ports but exposing the same one, specify a range of port numbers like in the following `docker-compose.yml` example:

```yaml
services:
  node-app:
...
    ports:
      - 6379-6381:5432
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
...
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? In my testing, it didn't work as expected. though ports in the range connect to the service, there is no stickiness. say if I sent a request to port 6379 for the 1st time It might be directed to replica 2. and if I sent another request to the same port again then It might be directed to replica 1 or 2 or 3.

Comment: @AnilTallam it sounds like you're thinking of a case opposite of what was asked here. The question and answer are about multiple instances of a Node.js service connecting to one instance of Redis. Stickiness is likely not relevant here because there's only one place that data is being stored, and if it is, it wasn't mentioned as a concern in the question